# Python Error-handeling names in a method

Tags: function, class, methods, error-handling, infinite-loop

So I'm trying to do a quiz, this is the first course I've ever taken in Python so I'm not that good at it. Anyway, I'm trying to do an error-handling for my players.

I'll try to describe what I'm trying to do and what I can't figure out.

So here's the code.

For some weird reason my come won't start where I want it to start. This is my first question here as well.

```
def save_names(self):
    playerlist = []
    current_players = []
    all_players_evey = list_of_all_players() #Makes all_players_ever into a list of names

for i in range(self.plyers): #just a number
    name=input("Pick a name")

    a=True
    while a:
        if name in self.current_players:
            print("Pick a different name")
            self.save_names(i)
        else:
            self.current_names.append(name)
            if (name+".txt") in all_players_ever:
                print("You already have a registered score")
                choice = input("1. wanna overwright your old score?\n2. Wanna save your old result?")
                if choice == "1":
                    a=False
                elif choice == "2":
                    self.save_names(i)    
                else:
                     print("Wrong choice")
            else:
                self.playerlist.append(name)
                a=False
return self.playerlist
```

So let's say there are 2 players this time.

So the first thing I want to check is so that the current players doesn't pick the same name. (Since in this case it's only 2 players, this will only be interesting when the second guy typing his name.)

So after that I want to check if I don't have a score saved in that name as a txt-file already.

And if I do, the player gets those 2 options.

If the person choose the first option(1) the script is fine. It just skips the iteration and go to the next player.

However if the person choose the second option which is 2, the script really messes up, in some strange loopy thing I can't get my head around. Same thing happens if the second player picks the same name as the first player.

So. The problem lies in the `self.save_names(i)` method if I'm not mistaken.

I hope you guys figure out what I want with the code, and come up with a brilliant solution!

Comment: If you think the problem is in `self.save_names`, why don't you include that code?

Comment: Find a debugger and step through your program to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hey man, what do you mean with include the code? I'm simply looking for someone to tell me way around it, so I don''t have to use the self.save_names() or how to fix that line. That debugger looks too difficult for me haha. Thx anyway!